# Connection to mysql database does not work c #

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to connect to my mysql database (I'm hosted by infinityfree.net), entering these credentials:

```
connection = new MySqlConnection("Server=sql306.epizy.com; Port=3306; Database=epiz_27674946_db1; Uid=epiz_27674946; Pwd=**********; ");
```

But I get this exception:

```
Unable to connect to any of the specified mysql hosts
```

I don't know why this happens, the credentials should be right...

Can you help me?

Full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace sharetru
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        MySqlConnection connection;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                connection = new MySqlConnection("Server=sql306.epizy.com; Port=3306; Database=epiz_27674946_db1; Uid=epiz_27674946; Pwd=*******; ");
                connection.Open();
                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    label1.Text = "Connected";
                    label1.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                }
                else
                {
                    label1.Text = "Not Connected";
                    label1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: are you _sure_ you can reach the server with those login credentials? have you verified it with a database tool?

Comment: `if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)` is a pointless if statement - the `else` is _incredibly_ unlikely to be entered.

Comment: @Franz Gleichmann can you provide me a database tester or something?

Comment: are you sure, that your mysql is open for external access? it is possible, that there are restrictions for accessing the Database for security reasons

Comment: @PietroContadini no. but google can. there's myriads of database tools out there.

Comment: @TinoZ I don't know honestly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding this service (infinityfree) it is not possible to access mysql from desktop applications (outside the infinityfree host)

https://support.infinityfree.net/mysql/how-to-connect-with-mysql/

Comment: last paragraph is the important part: `Finally, please note that it's NOT possible to connect to the free hosting databases from outside the hosting platform. This means you cannot access the database from desktop or mobile applications directly, or use them in applications hosted elsewhere.`

Answer (score -1):

The code looks correct. The issue probably is in the connection string details.

Are you able to connect using the following connection details via some GUI tool?
Workbench for example https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/